# ELMAH Filtering Programmatically not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, elmah

Elmah always kick in. How to filter programmatically:
Here is my Global file:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Filtering event of the ErrorLog control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="Elmah.ExceptionFilterEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    public void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Filter(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Filtering event of the ErrorMail control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="Elmah.ExceptionFilterEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    public void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Filter(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Filters the specified e.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="Elmah.ExceptionFilterEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void Filter(ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = e.Exception.GetBaseException();
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;

        if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            e.Dismiss();
        }

        if (exception is FileNotFoundException ||
            exception is HttpRequestValidationException ||
            exception is ViewStateException ||
            exception is CryptographicException ||
            exception is NodeNullException ||
            exception is SectionNullException ||
            exception is IdentifierNullException ||
            exception is AccessForbiddenException ||
            exception is HttpException)
        {
            e.Dismiss();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Error event of the Application control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool errorObtained = false;
        Exception ex = null;

        try
        {
            Exception rawException = Server.GetLastError();
            if (rawException != null)
            {
                errorObtained = true;
                if (rawException.InnerException != null)
                {
                    ex = rawException.InnerException;
                }
                else
                {
                    ex = rawException;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        if (errorObtained && ex != null)
        {
            if ((HttpContext.Current != null) && (HttpContext.Current.Request != null))
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
                {
                    Server.Transfer(errorPage, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if your Filter method is being called at all by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: NO. This is why it not firing

Comment: My web.config
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="errorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="errorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>

Comment: and http modules
      <add name="ErrorLogModule" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorMailModule" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorFilterModule" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>

Comment: Please look at answer to this nightmare
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224998/elmah-filtering-programmatically-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to name your HttpModules as:

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
<add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
<add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
```

with the exact names specified above